# Set Header On Active Sheet To Cell Value On Different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to something I would think is simple, basically I am trying to Set the header in one sheet to the value of a cell in another sheet.  I can't seem to get the cell reference working.  Here is the code I am working with:

```
Sub PrepareHeader()
   Sheet30.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&""Arial,Bold""&18 " & 
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

I cannot get the data from A1 on sheet1.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

Carry the **value** in `A1` from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` by setting the ranges equal to each other

```
Sub PrepareHeader()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```

---

### Option 2

Carry the **value & format** in `A1` from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` by using copy and paste

```
Sub PrepareHeaderV2()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

End Sub
```

---

### Note:

Adjust values of `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` to fit your needs. I doubt this is actually what you need, but hopefully you can see the proper syntax and apply as needed to your actual problem. If you are dealing with multiple workbooks, you can swap `ThisWorkbook` for `ActiveWorkbook` when needed. Similarly, `Sheets("Sheet1")` can be swapped with `ActiveSheet`. However, I do not advice doing either as code dependent on `Active` objects is not always reliable.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I thought it would work, but its not.  I need to set this: Sheet30.PageSetup.CenterHeader =

To equal the value in Sheet1 A1.

Comment: Explain what you mean with words, not code abbreviation please.